# String.IsNullOrEmpty like function for VARCHARs in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I've got a function or stored procedure that takes in several VARCHAR parameters.  I've gotten tired of writing SQL like this to test if these parameters have a value:

```
IF @SomeVarcharParm IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@SomeVarcharParm) > 0
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```

There's gotta be a better way to do this.  Isn't there?

Comment: Gosh, I shoulda known that.  Both answers work, of course.  Accepted Joe's answer since he posted first.

Comment: See my comment on Derek's answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do `ISNULL(@SomeVarcharParam, '') <> ''` or you can create a UDF that returns a bit:

```
create function dbo.IsNullOrEmpty(@x varchar(max)) returns bit as
BEGIN
IF @SomeVarcharParm IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@SomeVarcharParm) > 0
    RETURN 0
ELSE
    RETURN 1
END
```

And call that using `IF NOT dbo.IsNullOrEmpty(@SomeVarcharParam) BEGIN ...`

Keep in mind that when calling a UDF, you **MUST** prefix the owner of it (here, dbo.)

Comment: You should have emphasized the `ISNULL()` a little more because `COALESCE` uses it, thereby making `ISNULL()` more efficient. Consequentially, [`IsNull` is faster](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/196-SQL-COALESCE-Very-Cool-But-Slower-Than-ISNULL-.htm)

Comment: @Justin Satyr: Adam Machanic [demonstrated](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce.aspx) that the `ISNULL` is only 10-12% faster than `COALESCE` and, in his words, is "Hardly worth the functionality and standards compliance sacrifice." Furthermore, as Adam indicates in later comments on the article, the difference is gone completely in SQL Server 2008 and both have virtually identical performance.

Comment: @Joe, I didn't mean for the requester to actually change whose answer he accepted... Either way, *if* it is true that `COALESCE` refers to the `ISNULL` function, then even if the difference is O(1), `ISNULL` is still better for the same reason `return true` is better than `return FunctionThatReturnsTrue()`. It is less redundant. In your use, you never have need for `COALESCE`'s multiple value functionality. But there is a valid concern regarding standards.

Comment: My assumption is that you should also trim parameter before make a decision that it is empty. Are you agree?

Comment: Actually this is much shorter and easier to read: '@SomeVarcharParm > ''` And it doesn’t need a custom function. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75730174/4776207).

Answer (score 15):

```
IF COALESCE(@SomeVarcharParm, '') <> ''
BEGIN
   -- do stuff
END
```

Comment: This is a nice way though not easy to understand at first sight.

Comment: This is just simple, beautiful and smart.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5):

If I'm concatenating or coalescing a string inline (within a select statement), and I want to check if the column is NULL or Empty, I do this:

```
ISNULL('starting to build string ' 
+ NULLIF(some_table..some_col_that_might_be_null_or_empty, '')
, 'string to append if the resulting concatenation is null')
```

The NULLIF on the inner part of the expression will force the column to be NULL if it's empty, then the outer ISNULL expression can depend on consistent input and react accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted Atron's answer though he technically implemented `IfNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Here's my implementation of `IfNullOrEmpty()`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys .objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[IfNullOrEmpty]' ) and type in ( N'FN'))
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.IfNullOrEmpty
go

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IfNullOrEmpty(@value varchar(max), @substitute varchar(max)) returns varchar(max) as
BEGIN
    IF @value IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@value) > 0
        RETURN @value
    RETURN @substitute  
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function that "extends" ISNULL and checks for empty as well. The test value is checked for null and if it is not null it is trimmed and then checked for length.

The function returns the test string if it is NOT Null or Empty, otherwise the second string is returned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ISNULLOREMPTY]
(   
    @value NVARCHAR(max),
    @return NVARCHAR(max)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 

IF (@value IS NULL)
BEGIN
    RETURN @return
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF (LEN(LTRIM(@value)) = 0)
    BEGIN 
        RETURN @return
    END 
END

RETURN @value;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but this is what I use in MSSQL:
`LEN(ISNULL(@asdf, ''))>0`

Example:

```
DECLARE @asdf varchar(10)
SET @asdf = NULL --You can change this value to test different outputs

BEGIN IF LEN(ISNULL(@asdf, '')) > 0
   PRINT @asdf
ELSE
   PRINT 'IS NullOrEmpty'
END

--You can use it inline like this:
PRINT CASE LEN(ISNULL(@asdf, '')) WHEN 0 THEN 'IS NullOrEmpty' ELSE @asdf END
```

I think this is simpler and more straight forward than the other solutions because it is literally checking if the string is null or has a length of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for null before calling LEN. You can just use LEN(@SomeVarcharParm) > 0. This will return false if the value is NULL, '', or ' '. This is because NULL > 0 returns false. See for yourself run:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN NULL > 0 THEN 'NULL > 0 = true' ELSE 'NULL > 0 = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN(NULL) > 0 THEN 'LEN(NULL) = true' ELSE 'LEN(NULL) = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN('') > 0 THEN 'LEN('''') > 0 = true' ELSE 'LEN('''') > 0 = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN(' ') > 0 THEN 'LEN('' '') > 0 = true' ELSE 'LEN('' '') > 0 = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN(' test ') > 0 THEN 'LEN('' test '') > 0 = true' ELSE 'LEN('' test '') > 0 = false' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `IF @SomeVarcharParam <> ''` since the condition will evaluate to `NULL` and the branch won't be taken if the parameter is null

Comment: You maybe got the best answer here, but can you be more clear about the NULL not evaluated ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function (based on Derek's):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isNullOrEmpty(@x varchar(max)) RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
    IF @x IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@x) > 0
        RETURN 0

    RETURN 1
END
```

as

```
dbo.isNullOrEmpty(@someVar)
```

or

```
WHERE dbo.isNullOrEmpty(@someVar) = 1
```

in a stored procedure or query.

Answer (score 0):

please use case command.case structure is:

case when condition then 'some value' else 'some other value' end

some example:

```
declare @SomeVarcharParm as nvarchar(20)=''
declare @SomeVarcharParm2 as nvarchar(20)=''

--select 1 or 2
select case when @SomeVarcharParm is null or @SomeVarcharParm='' then 1 else 2 end


--if null or empty set 'empty' value else set @SomeVarcharParm value
select @SomeVarcharParm2=case when @SomeVarcharParm is null or @SomeVarcharParm='' then 'empty' else @SomeVarcharParm end


--use null or empty in update command
update tbl1
set field1=case when field1 is null or field1='' then @SomeVarcharParm2 else field1 end
where id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the shortest solution would be:

```sql
IF @SomeVarcharParm > ''
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```

It doesen't need a custom function and it has the advantage, that you don't need to compute on @SomeVarcharParm, so this approach, used in a Where clause would allow the use of an index.

```sql
Select
    [NULL]   = Case When  NULL > ''   Then 'has content' Else 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' End,  -- → IsNullOrWhiteSpace
    ['']     = Case When  '' > ''     Then 'has content' Else 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' End,  -- → IsNullOrWhiteSpace
    ['  ']   = Case When  '  ' > ''   Then 'has content' Else 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' End,  -- → IsNullOrWhiteSpace
    [' x']   = Case When  ' x' > ''   Then 'has content' Else 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' End,  -- → has content
    ['Sepp'] = Case When  'Sepp' > '' Then 'has content' Else 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' End,  -- → has content
    ['-1']   = Case When  '-1' > ''   Then 'has content' Else 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace' End   -- → has content
;
```