# SQL Server 2008R2: Evaluating three columns case statements or coalesce?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have been working on figuring out how to accomplish the following for a few days now: 
I have one table which has alternate addresses, but I only need to pull the city. However the city might be in field5,field4, or field3. What I would like to do, and have failed miserably, is to populate another field called city with the value found through evaluating the three fields for <> NULL.

This is what I have so far, although I'm not receiving any errors, the only value that appears is field4, since field5 is null or ''. But if field4 is also null, the city field is blank. For some reason my query is not looking at field3 and if there is a value, the value won't populate. Help please!

This is the 1st attempt:
case when altcity='Y' and (field5 IS null OR field5=' ' ) 
then field4 else
    case when altcity='Y' and (field4 IS null OR field4=' ')
    then field3
        else field5
    end 
end as city <- Field5 or Field4 appears as it should, but if both fields are null, the field is blank. Looks as if the query doesn't look at field3.

Here is the second attempt:

```
case when altcity='y' then coalesce(field5,field4,field3) end as city
```

Same thing here, the value in field5 or field4 is populated, but the value for field3 does not.

Thank you already very much for assisting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit long handed but what does the following look like when run against your data:

```
CASE 
    WHEN altcity='y' THEN   
                        CASE
                            WHEN field5 is not null AND field5 != '' THEN field5
                            WHEN ((field5 is null) OR (field5 = '')) and ((field4 is not null) AND (field4 != ''))  then field4
                            WHEN (((field5 is null) OR (field5 = '')) and ((field4 is null) OR (field4 = ''))) and ((field3 is not null) AND (field3 != '')) then field3
                            ELSE '?'
                        END
    END
```

Having seen an example of your data it now makes sense that the `COALESCE` didn't work as that is reliant on NULL's in the data. In C# there is a string function `IsNullOrEmpty` that handles these cases. T-SQL doesn't have this but there are examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863120/string-isnullorempty-like-function-for-varchars-in-sql) that help create that functionality and could tidy up the case statement

Comment: Thank you @Matt for the quick response! I've ran the suggestion against my data and the only field which is pulling now is field5 and not any of the others when field5 is null. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is field5 actually null or is it just blank (empty string)?

Comment: Field5 can be both either null or blank.

Comment: An example of the line is altadd='Y', field3='Yorktown', field4=      , field5=NULL; then another line is altadd='Y', field3='Yorktown', field4=NULL, field5=     ;

Comment: Hi @DeanaJacobus I've updated the case statement, give that a go.

Comment: You are a genius Matt! Thank you so very much for the hard work and answer. You are amazing! I apologize for just now getting back on here, but I didn't receive an update that there was a response :(